# JavaFX Canvas distorts image

Tags: java, image, canvas, javafx

I am adding a frame to an image in JavaFX by first adding the frame to the canvas and then the image,
so that it overlaps and the image seems to have a frame.

For some reason my image gets distorted, it scales poorly and makes everything in it look "fat". 
If I try to show the image in an `ImageView` (variable named "image" in the code) it looks normal, 
so I tried to get the values (`width` and `height`) from the normal looking `ImageView`, yet still no luck:

```
Image i = new Image(path.toUri().toString());
image.setImage(i);

canvas.setWidth(image.getFitWidth() + 20);
canvas.setHeight(image.getFitHeight() + 20);

GraphicsContext gc1 = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc1.drawImage(rimage, 0, 0, image.getFitWidth() + 20, image.getFitHeight() + 20);

GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
image.preserveRatioProperty();
gc.drawImage(i, 10, 10, image.getFitWidth(), image.getFitHeight());
```

Original image:

[image: Original]

Framed and distorted (the head looks rounder):

[image: Framed and distorted]

Comment: Could you maybe post screenshots of the two images here (what it should look like if you can, and what it does look like)? Also, what type of object is your canvas variable?

Comment: @clearlyspam23 I added the photos and I am using: Canvas canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this myself, but theres a few things I noticed about your code.

First, the line

```
image.preserveRatioProperty();
```

doesn't actually change any state for the ImageView, all it does is tell you whether or not the ImageView is set to preserve ratios.

what you probably want instead is:

```
image.setPreserveRatio(true);
```

which I believe will probably do what you want.

If it doesn't it might be because the image has already been loaded, so if this still doesn't work, try putting `image.setPreserveRatio(true);` before `image.setImage(i);`

Comment: Tried adding 'image.setPreserveRatio(true)' in various places but still no luck. Putting 'image.setPreserveRatio(true);' before 'image.setImage(i);' didn't work either.

Comment: have you tried doing the previous changes, but also removing the lines setting the canvas width and height? or maybe instead setting the canvas width and height to be the width and height of the `Image` rather than the height of the `ImageView`?

Comment: Yes I've tried removing the lines but can't use the size of the Image. The image is too large and messes up the layout of the program. The ImageView scales it accordingly, that's why I chose to use that size. Is there any easy way to scale the image automatically to fit the canvas size?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what else to try at this point. Maybe you could try using a different LayoutManager? or maybe you could manually set the ImageView's width and height via `resize`?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the window just too wide for your image? Try to crop the image using another drawImage where you can define which part of the image you want to use. Or change the window size. Or use a width and height to draw with that is relative to the one in the image.